# Datatable test with Cucumber and Scala

Tags: scala, datatable, cucumber

I am trying to create a simple calculator app using Cucumber/Gherkins and Scala where the information is given in a datatable but not sure how to go about this? I'm quite new to BDD testing and wanted to know how other programmers have overcome this

I've created a feature file with other operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication and division where the values are provided within the 'when, then' statements which works fine but not sure how to handle datatables within Cucumber using Scala.

Any help would be much appreciated

Feature File:

```
Scenario Outline: Addition
Given my calculator is running
When I add <inputOne> and <inputTwo>
Then result should be equal to <output>
Examples:
  | inputOne | inputTwo | output |
  | 20       | 30       | 50     |
  | 2        | 5        | 7      |
  | 0        | 40       | 40     |
```

Step definition file:

```
class CalcSteps extends ScalaDsl with EN {

var calc: MyCalc = _
var result: Int= _

Given("""^my calculator is running$""") { () =>
calc = new MyCalc 
}

When("^I add \"(.*?)\" and \"(.*?)\":$") { (firstNum: Int, secondNum: Int, values: DataTable) =>
//not sure what to do here
//result = calc.add(firstNum, secondNum)
}

Then("^result should be equal to \"(.*?)\"$") { (expectedResult: Int) =>
assert(result == expectedResult, "Incorrect result of calculator computation")
```

}

MyCalc:

```
class MyCalc {

 def add(first:Int, second: Int): Int = {
   first + second
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a 'scenario outline', that way each addition is a test. So in your case you will have 3 tests.  Datatable is used to pass details which are needed for a single test. I know nothing about Scala, but as it is based on Java, the step definition you are using is not correct. In Java, you have to use a DataTable to get the values as a kind of 2 dim array. You can even use a List or Map instead.

Comment: thanks for the heads up about the Scenario Outline. I have corrected this now. do you happen to have an example of a datatable being used in java? thanks

Comment: You do not need datatable code anymore... Your original code should work. Remove the ", values: DataTable" from the step definition.

Comment: thank you so much :) works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Grasshopper I was able to resolve the issue by simply changing the feature file to:

```
Scenario Outline: Addition
Given my calculator is running
When I add <inputOne> and <inputTwo>
Then result should be equal to <output>
Examples:
  | inputOne | inputTwo | output |
  | 20       | 30       | 50     |
  | 2        | 5        | 7      |
  | 0        | 40       | 40     |
```

and removing the 'values:Datatable' field from the step definition which results in:

```
  When("^I add \"(.*?)\" and \"(.*?)\":$") { (firstNum: Int, secondNum: Int) =>

result = calc.add(firstNum, secondNum)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user610 and Grasshopper, I was looking for cucumber example with test cases written in datatable structure, but most example online is not in Scala. This is a perfect and clear example!